# What would be the most 'lightweight' way to observe current time for a an android composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

What would be the most `lightweight` way to observe current time from viewModel from a composable.

In my composable's view I would expect to see current time formatted as `HH:mm` and be always updated according to current time.

Comment: [`java.time.LocalTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#now--) is an option

Comment: Should I use a flow on a viewModel and then collect it from composable? And what would be the best method in order to trigger less recompositions from a composable? Those are the things I also have in my mind...

Comment: I'd prefer the `ViewModel`…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LaunchedEffect as in example below. I added seconds to show that it updates, you can change delay and formatting according to your needs.

```
@Composable
private fun Timer() {
    var time by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val sdf = remember { SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.ROOT)}
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        while(isActive){
           time = sdf.format(Date())
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
    Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(time, fontSize = 40.sp)

    }
}
```

In ViewModel with `MutableStateFlow`

```
class TimerModel(private val dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat) : ViewModel() {
    private val _timer = MutableStateFlow<String>(dateFormat.format(Date()))
    val timer: StateFlow<String> = _timer

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (isActive) {
                _timer.value = dateFormat.format(Date())
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
val currentTime = timeViewModel.timer.collectAsState()
Text(currentTime.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi this answer is nice but I would prefer a solution from viewModel because I would like to observe it in other parts of code also and make other calculations also.

Comment: @F.Mysir added another sample with ViewModel

Comment: The answer is very good except for the use of an outdated library (`java.util.Date` & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are not recommended anymore). Use `java.time` instead, if you can…