# How to change the Default value of a variable after some time?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is it possible in KOTLIN or by remember in Jetpack Compose to change the value of a variable after some seconds?

For example, I have a variable `var currentResult1 = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }`.
How can I say that after my activity opens, this currentResult1.value change to false after 1 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change value of any `MutableState` value using `LaunchedEffect` or `coroutineScope` builder functions.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(1000)
    currentResult1.value = false
}
```

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333458/5457853) how to use it for a timer that changes current value every second.